# Which one is right: in, on, or at the market?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I want to translate [this page](http://www.ebrahimco.com/part-cat/16-glass_cleaning_equipment), but I have a problem:

> 1. on the market
> 2. in the market
> 3. at the market?

Which one is correct? I want use it for an object.

Answer (score 4):

> At the market.

You are physically at the market, buying some flowers, for example.

> On the market

To be available for purchase: "My car is on the market for $6799"

> In the market:

To be actively looking for something to purchase: "I'm in the market for a new car", which means I would like to buy a new car.

Note that *in the market*, could *also* mean that you are *physically inside* the market, but used when location (inside or outside) in important. For example, some friends are in the street, near a market place (i.e. outside the market), and one says "Where is John?". A reply could be "John is *in* the market, buying some flowers."

Answer (score 0):

"At the market" may also mean "at a price consistent with current market prices." The only one who can tell which phrase is apposite is someone who fully understands the language in which the text that you are trying to translate is written.